# How to fix search bar in VS Code Jupyter with find input shrunken by translated characters

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, searchbar

[image: Error of searchbox bar]

The search keyword input field is hidden but active. The search is done blindly. This is a problem with Jupyter Notebook only in VS Code.

Comment: Image is too small. Try to add image with good scale.

Answer (score 0):

The error was fixed when I changed the interface language to English

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).